How can i make this dropdown menu long all the page width?
I have this Bootstrap 5 megamenu and I want to make all the dropdown menus long all the page width and all have the same position.
Like this page.
How can I make the dropdown menus larger?
Which Bootstrap class do I have to modify?
I have tried but nothing has changed. I don't know why.


.navbar-nav {
  max-width: 950px;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 1225px;
  z-index: 999;
}

#navbarSupportedContent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  color: darkgrey;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu li:first-child a {
  color: darkgrey;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
<!-- Bootstrap-5 Dependencies -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-I7E8VVD/ismYTF4hNIPjVp/Zjvgyol6VFvRkX/vR+Vc4jQkC+hVqc2pM8ODewa9r" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<nav id="navbar_top" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>




You can do it like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/SaoudiH/u9bpryzo/7/
You need to add these two classes:
.navbar .has-megamenu{position:static!important;}
.navbar .megamenu{left:0; right:0; width:100%; margin-top:0;  }

Apply megamenu to the dropdown-menu element and has-megamenu to its parent.
Example:
<li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Lorem</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu megamenu">

Check this resource:
https://bootstrap-menu.com/detail-megamenu.html

wait sorry... i made this menu sticky if i scroll the page. if i don't scroll the page the dropdown menu stay inside the body width(that has max-width:1220px) but if i scroll down the page and the menu become sticky on top, the dropdown menu become 100% of the page width (as i want). how can i fix this?

Hi, sorry I didn't see your message earlier. You should share your code with more details about the issue. Here is an attempt at a solution, but I'm not sure if it addresses the real problem you described
https://jsfiddle.net/SaoudiH/u9bpryzo/29/
